# Change object property value in cakephp 3

Tags: object, cakephp-3.0

My index action is like

```
public function index() {
    $acos = $this->Acos->find('threaded');
    foreach ($acos as $aco) {
        $aco->children = doSomeOperations($aco->children);
    }
}
```

I want to replace $acos->$aco->children value by its new value but I can't do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the reference operator

```
public function index() {
    $acos = $this->Acos->find('threaded');
    foreach ($acos as &$aco) {
        $aco->children = doSomeOperations($aco->children);
    }
}
```

Another way is using the collection methods in the result set:

```
$acos = $this->Acos->find('threaded')
    ->map(function ($aco) {
        $aco->children = doSomeOperations($aco->children);
        return $aco;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you dear @Jose. I test your solutions but first solution results this error "An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference" and second solution results "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"

Comment: Where are you serializing the closure? You can call `->toArray()` at the end to make sure you are not going to serialize a closure. If you are not doing that by yourself, make sure you have updated the DebugKit plugin to its latest version as that was an known bug.

Comment: You are right. I disable debugkit and it worked properly. 1)Can you please give a direct link to download debugkit. I don't access to cmd to use "php composer.phar require cakephp/debug_kit" 2)Do you guess what is the problem of &$aco in first solution?

Comment: The problem is that the Query returns an iterator not an array. But you can call `->toArray()` so you can iterate and change like a normal array.